# How to make Next.js transition between URLs smoothly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have on one URL (`pages/index.js`) an `<input onFocus={() => router.push('/search')} />`, and on the `/search` url (`pages/search.js`) I have a full form. However, it jolts and flickers when going from one screen to the next. How do I avoid that?

[image]

Comment: That's usually more prominent during development. Try running a production build locally with `next build && next start` and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to setup nprogress loading when navigating between pages :

```
_app.js

import NProgress from "nprogress";
import Router from "next/router";
import "nprogress/nprogress.css";


NProgress.configure({ showSpinner: true });

Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => {
  NProgress.start();
});
Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => {
  NProgress.done();
});
```

Custom css for nprogress :

```
#nprogress {
  color: green !important;
}

#nprogress .bar {
  background: green !important;
}

#nprogress .spinner-icon {
  border-top-color: green !important;
  border-left-color: green !important;
}
```

***Note***

If you don't want to have a flicker meaning no navigating between pages then you should handle input focus with states to show the form :

```
function Form() {
    const [show , setShow] = React.useState(false)
    return (
        <div>
            {show ? <YourFormComponent/> : <input onFocus={()=>setShow(true)} ></input>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

***Extra Note***

If you want to update the url and have your inputs show I suggest using queries :

```
import React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import queryString from "query-string";

function FormWithQuery() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const parsed = queryString.parse(router.query);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // your logic here
    setShow(true);
  }, [parsed]);

  return (
    <div>
      {show ? (
        <FormComponent />
      ) : (
        <input onFocus={() => router.push("/?searchForm=true")} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormWithQuery;
```

Comment: In my case I would like for it to appear as if nothing happened when transitioning between urls, just that the form "expands" from just the input.

Comment: @LancePollard I've edited the answer please accept it if it helped you in anyway

Comment: Right I understand your update, but I want to change the URL too, without flicker.

Comment: @LancePollard I added extra notes please accept answer if it helped you in anyway